# I want to handle Google Work Space Group mail with a service account, but authentication does not work

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth, gmail, gmail-api

#### What I would like to resolve.

I would like to operate my company's Google Work Space Group email via a service account, but authentication is not working.
I am getting an HttpError 400 error, and I feel that I do not have enough authentication information or authorization, but I am having trouble identifying the cause. Since GCP is used by my company, I cannot apply for authorization many times, so I would like to narrow down the cause and solution to some extent, so I would appreciate your advice.
I would like to narrow down the cause and solution to some extent, so I would like to get your advice.

What we ultimately want to do is: **We want to use a service account to handle Gmail. ** That's all.

Thank you in advance.

<Current IAM permissions
Role of the user you are operating as (me)

- Editor
- Service account administrator

#### What I have tried by myself

- Activated Gmailapi, confirmed.
- Authenticated with user account -> Successfully retrieved Gmail, confirmed.

Service account key json file is as follows. (some parts are rewritten)

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

```json
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": “my-project”,
  "private_key_id": “12345678xxxxxxxxxxxx”,
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": “my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": “12345678901234567890”,
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my-project%40vmy-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

This is the python code that is being executed.
As an example, the email can be retrieved by running it with 1.User Account Ver, which is commented out below.

```py
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
# from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials #User Account Vertion

MAXRESULT= 100
SCOPE    = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
user_key = '../user_token.json'
sa_key   = '../service_account_token.json'
query    = "company_group@company.co.jp"

### 1.User Account Vertion----------
# creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(user_key, SCOPE)

### 2.Service Account Vertion ----------
creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file(sa_key, scopes=SCOPE)

try:
    # Call the Gmail API
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])
    # Token Verification
    print("cred.token: {}\ncreds.valid: {}".format(creds.token, creds.valid))

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')

    ### Get mail list
    messageIDlist = service.users().messages().list(userId="me", maxResults=MAXRESULT, q=query).execute()
    mes = messageIDlist["messages"]
    print("mes_id:{}".format(mes[0]['id']))
    pprint(service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=mes[0]['id']).execute())

except HttpError as error:
    # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

#### Problem/Error occurring

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.". Details: "[{'message': 'Precondition check failed.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'failedPrecondition'}]">
```

"https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels?alt=json"
When I open the url, I get this message。

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.ListLabels",
          "service": "gmail.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please comment on any other information you need and I will add it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To use a service account with Gmail you must delegate to a user on your domain

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

# Path to the Service Account's Private Key file
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH = "C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\workspaceserviceaccount.json"


def create_delegated_gmail_service(user_email):
    """Build and return a gmail service object authorized with the service
  account that acts on behalf of the given user.

  Args:
    user_email: The email of the user to impersonate. Needs permissions to access gmail.
  Returns:
    Cloud Search Query API service object that is ready to make requests.
  """

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH,
        scopes=SCOPES)

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)

    return build("gmail", "v1", credentials=credentials)


def main(user_email):
    service = create_delegated_gmail_service(user_email)
    # Call the Gmail v1 API
    results = service.users().messages().list(
        userId='me').execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])

    if not messages:
        print('No messages found.')
        return
    print('Messages:')
    for message in messages:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(message['id'], message['threadId']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("user@yourdomain.com")
```

Without delegating to a user on the domain you will get a `"Precondition check failed."` error as the service account itself doesn't have a gmail account.

Pro tip make sure you have given the service account access to the `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'` scope